# How can I retrieve a list of terms from an Examine index?

Tags: c#, lucene, umbraco, examine

I have implemented Examine in an Umbraco project and have created an index of my site's content. What I now need is a list of terms stored in that index for any given field.

This list of terms will be the basis for an autocomplete search field of a UI form.

How can I retrieve this list of terms based upon a specific field, e.g. nodeName?

Please note, I do not want to search against the nodeName field. I wish to read/retrieve the terms in the index associated with the field.

Comment: I haven't found an answer for this yet, but what I have done instead is create and open a Lucene IndexReader instance and used the instance's reader.Terms() method. The issue with this is that I have had to create a layer of functionality for controlling single instances of the IndexReaders used, etc. which is additional bloat for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not possible but since the Examine library is based upon the Lucene library, it is a matter of "rolling your own" and just opening and interrogating an `IndexReader` instance using the `reader.Terms()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
reader.terms(new Term("nodeName", ""));
```

Comment: I am doing this already. Please read the question and my comment underneath. I wish to read terms using the Examine library without implementing a purely Lucene solution.